# How do you convert multiple columns to date format in R using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a database with multiple columns of dates as character class. I want to use the lubridate package in R to convert them all at once. I'm  not having trouble parsing the date format, but in applying lubridate over multiple columns. Any suggestions?

```
crimes.df <- data.frame(offense.date = c('06102003', '05122006'), charge.date = c('07152003', '10012010'))
```

I have tried

```
crimes.df[,1:2]<-mdy(crimes.df[,1:2])
```

and

```
crimes.df[,1:2]<-lapply(crimes.df[,1:2], function(x) mdy(crimes.df[,1:2]))
```

both return this error:

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

(and, inconveniently, wipe out all data in the columns.)

Answer (score 3):

Using `lapply`, we are looping the columns of the dataset and the function `mdy` is applied on each `column`.

```
crimes.df[] <- lapply(crimes.df, mdy)
```

---

In the OP's code, if we are calling the anonymous function (`function(x)`), then the function (`mdy`) should be applied on 'x'

```
crimes.df[] <- lapply(crimes.df, function(x) mdy(x))
```

Also, note that since there are only 2 columns, we don't need to specify the `crimes.df[,1:2]`

Comment: I stumbled my way to a solution, but yours is much more elegant. I did:   gcm.dates[,2:12]<-lapply(gcm.dates[,2:12], function(x) mdy(x)). I still got the error message, but the dates converted and I lost not data.